# PHP: Replace \r\n with a real line break

Tags: php, sqlite

I try to modify a sql file created by mysqldump to import it to a SQLite database. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626296/newlines-migration-from-mysql-to-sqlite) I have already asked how to do this and got the answer that I have to replace e.g. "\r\n" with a new line.

Well, my question on the mentioned answer is whether and how is it possible to put a real line break into a string with PHP.

Example:
Input: "Nice sentence. Also a nice sentence."

Output: "Nice sentence.

Also a nice sentence."

Comment: Lots of examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098488/problem-replacing-literal-string-r-n-with-line-break-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Note: $source is assigned with single quotes, which means that
// the \r\n will not be interpolated
$source = 'Nice sentence.\r\nAlso a nice sentence.';
$destination = str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), array("\r", "\n"), $source);
```

Comment: Well, that was easier than expected. Thanks a lot, looks good! :)